# How to hook up a laptop to a Dish satellite?

Tags: laptop, hdmi

I'm trying to watch movies from my laptop on an actual TV. The TV itself does not have an HDMI port, but the dish satellite (ViP722 DVR) does. Is it possible to do this through a dish satellite using HDMI? And if so, how?

Comment: that port on the dish box is for connecting to a TV, you cannot connect your laptop to it without damage. What kinds of ports does your TV have?

Answer (score 1):

According to the instruction manual for that particular DVR (downloadable from [this website](http://www.mydish.com/support/receiver-manuals)), the HDMI output is only usable for output from the DVR to your television, and cannot be used for input from your laptop computer.